# OMP: Error #131: Thread identifier invalid. when use Numba @njit(nogil=True, parallel=True)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I want to speed up my code by parallel in Numba (0.55.1 version) as below: As it contain a for loop, I want to speed it up by parallel computing with Numba

```
from numba import prange
from numba import njit
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
import time

@njit(nogil=True)
def func(n):
    nprime = n-1
    main = np.sqrt(2.) * np.random.normal(0., 1., (nprime))
    off = np.random.normal(0., 1., (nprime, nprime))
    tril = np.tril(off, -1)
    W_n = tril + tril.T
    np.fill_diagonal(W_n, main)

    eigenvalues = LA.eigvals(W_n)
    return np.sort(eigenvalues)[::-1][0:2]

@njit(nogil=True, parallel=True)
def GOE_L12_sim_pa(n=200, rep=500):
    for x0 in prange(rep):
        func(n)

start = time.time()
GOE_L12_sim_pa()
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Error:

```
OMP: Error #131: Thread identifier invalid.
OMP: Error #131: Thread identifier invalid.
```

Noting that it works when I change the decorator from `@njit(nogil=True, parallel=True)` to `@njit(nogil=True)`.

Comment: This is certainly a bug and the new version of Numba appear not to have it (at least not the 0.55.1). Can you provide the Numba version and/or test newer versions?

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is strange. Interesting. It looks like the something else matters and we use a different configuration. I am on Windows and I also use the OpenMP backend. Can you report the value of `nb.np.ufunc.parallel.threading_layer()` and your platform ?

Comment: I got this error when I print the value. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numba_para.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(nb.np.ufunc.parallel.threading_layer())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/parallel.py", line 335, in threading_layer
    raise ValueError("Threading layer is not initialized.")
ValueError: Threading layer is not initialized.`

Comment: Ha, right! The Runtime is unfortunately not initialized before calling a Numba function... Thus, you need to write a basic parallel Numba function first and run it so the runtime can be printed. (not very convenient)

Comment: @JérômeRichard Could you show me an example and post it to the answer part?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same OMP #131 error due to a bug in llvm-openmp 12.0.0 running on the M1 Mac processor. Updating to the latest version 14.0.6 resolved the issue.